# Does this code having lineage issue?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I wrote some spark program to do calculation. The logic is very simple but it will always report OutOfMemory issue after a while. The logic is too simple to have memory leak.. And I am pretty sure my memory is enough. So I am wondering if it is lineage cost. Please help to give some advice... It really drive me crazy..

First this is not a stream computing although it looks like one.

The pseudo code:

```
for file_name in file_list:
    data_frame = get_data_frame(file_name)
    # The file_name is timestamp
    timestamp = file_name 
    my_dict[ timestamp ] = data_frame

    for the_timestamp in my_dict.keys():
        if timestamp - the_timestamp > 24 hours:
            # not only unpersist, but also delete to make sure the memory is released 
            my_dict[the_timestamp].unpersist
            del my_dict[the_timestamp ] 

    # pop one data frame from the dict
    big_data_frame = my_dict.popitem()

    for timestamp in my_dict.keys():
        df = my_dict.get( timestamp )
        big_data_frame = big_data_frame.unionAll(df)

    # Then we run SQL on the big_data_frame to get report
```

To explain the code again if still not clear. I have a list of files. Each file is having a timestamp as its name. I will read the files one by one to get a batch of data frame.  (I can not read them at once because the files are generated with time. not at once )

But I need to get the report on recent 288 files (The files are generated every 5 minutes, so recent 288 files represent for recent 1 day ).  So I maintain a dict. Every time I read a file and generate a data frame. I put it into the dict and remove those old ones (only those older than 1 day). Then I will merge the dataframe in the dict into a big one and run SQL to get some report.

I am running the program on a standalone cluster. Only one node. The driver has 4G memory, the executor has 6G memory. The file size is very small because I am doing test (4KB), so even the total size of 288 file is only 4kb * 288 ~ 1200KB. Far away from 4GB.

So I do not know why it reporting OutOfMemory or GC overlimit...

One thing I am not sure is that lineage issue. I read the spark stream doc, it said stream compute with operation like reduceByKeyandWindow need checkpoint to truncate lineage. I am not using stream compute by my code pattern have some common with the reduceByKeyandWindow.. Still I am not sure if it is the lineage or something else.

Please help to give some advice..

Comment: Lineage problems result with StackOverflow not GC or OOM.

Comment: @CafeFeed Thanks very much